# Template doesnot exist when running on heroku but exists when running locally

Tags: heroku, local

I just created my first heroku app and pushed my code through it onto heroku. While testing it however, it showed that one of the templates didnot exist when it infact does when I test it from my laptop directly on the local server. Please do guide if you have any ideas!(ps.: I am using Windows hence please do keep take that into consideration when helping out!)

Comment: The obvious guess (that's all we can do based on what little you've told us) is that the file _isn't_ in fact on Heroku. Did you commit it to your repository and push that branch to Heroku's `master` branch? Please read [ask].

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks! I am sorry would be more elaborate with the questions in the future. Basically I realized the name of the template was wrong on the views page. For others so that it is helpful, sometimes while otree may ignore the formatting issues on your local server, Heroku wont. So make sure that you are consistent with the formatting (capital A or not etc) on Heroku when you are writing your templates, and other files on Otree